# What is the 'the default user interface' referred to by the aShowDefaultUI parameter in element.execCommand()?

Tags: javascript, web, wysiwyg, client-side, rich-text-editor

According to the [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) for the element.execCommand() function, it says that it has three parameters: aCommandName, aShowDefaultUI, aValueArgument.

The API's description of the first and third parameters is perfectly clear but I'm unsure about the meaning of the second parameter.

This is what the API says:

> **aShowDefaultUI**:    A Boolean indicating whether the default user interface should be shown. This is not implemented in Mozilla.

What is it referring to when it says 'the default user interface'?

For reference, I'm using element.execCommand() to create my own WYSIWYG web text editor that will only ever need to work in Google Chrome.

Comment: The second argument originates to old IEs. Ex. when `true` in `createLink`, IE shows a pop-up to user to enter the protocol and URL for the link. Edge, FF and Chrome don't seem to do anything with the argument.

Comment: Hi @Teemu , thanks for your reply. Since I'm only going to be using this in Google Chrome would you suggest that I always set this argument to false?

Comment: It actually doesn't matter. FF ignores it, probably Chrome and Edge too, at least no influence can't be seen in Chrome or Edge.

Comment: OK, thanks for the information @Teemu

Comment: @Teemu your comment  should be an answer and I'd like to upvote it as such.

Answer (score -1):

**It's generally useless**

The second argument originates to old IEs. Ex. when `true` in createLink, IE shows a pop-up to user to enter the protocol and URL for the link. Edge, FF and Chrome don't seem to do anything with the argument.

Copied from @Teemu in comments

Comment: Please don't copy comments as your answers